# How to send an error to user that already add book to favorite

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to make a user stop adding a book into favorite when they already added and show the message into template. 
Here's my class django python:

```
class User(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                    related_name="book_uploaded", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = BookManager()


class Like(models.Model):
    u_like = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="user_like", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b_like = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, related_name="book_like", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And here's my `views.py`:

```
def book_info(request, id):

    user_who_like = Book.objects.get(id=id).book_like.all()

    context = {
        'book': Book.objects.get(id=id),
        'user': User.objects.get(id=request.session["user_id"]),
        'user_who_like': Book.objects.get(id=id).book_like.all(),
        'user_uploaded': Book.objects.first().uploaded_by,
    }
    return render(request, 'book_info.html', context)

def like(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session["user_id"])
    like = Like.objects.create(u_like=user, b_like=book)

    return redirect(f"/books/{book.id}")
```

Appreciate all your help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def like(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session["user_id"])
    like = Like.objects.get_or_create(u_like=user, b_like=book)

    if not like[1]:
        message = "Already added to favourite"

    return redirect(f"/books/{book.id}")
```

Here, what `get_or_create` does is it creates an object if the object is not already present and it returns a tuple, the object itself and a boolean value. If the object is newly created then it will return True otherwise False. You can then send this message on you template in a conventional way.

Comment: thanks man!! But how you make it only show to the book already added?

Comment: The tuple returned from ```get_or_create``` will return like[1] equals True if and only if a new object is created or say the book was not already added. So you can send you desired message to template if like[1] equals False or say book was already added. Otherwise you can send a blank message so the template condition don't trigger

Comment: So how can I write it in template?

Answer (score 0):

this is my def:

```
def like(request, id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session["user_id"])
    like = Like.objects.get_or_create(u_like=user, b_like=book)
    if not like[1]:
        messages.error(request,"Already added to favorite",extra_tags="like_error") 
        return redirect("/books/")
    context = {
        'like1': like[1],
    }

    return redirect(f"/books/{book.id}")
```

and here's my template:

```
<form action="/books/{{book.id}}/like/" method="post" class="like">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn far fa-thumbs-up"></button>

    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {% if "like_error" in message.tags %}
        <li class="text-danger">{{ message }}</li>
        {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {%endif%}

</form>
```